# Is this proof false, or I'm I wrong?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I have reviewed a paper and it appears that the proof is false to me, because of a line. Here is the line which happens for all $n\in \mathbb{N},$

\begin{align} [1-\alpha_{n}(k+1)]d^{2}(x_{n+1},u) &\leq [1+\alpha_{n}(1-2k)]d^{2}(x_{n},u)+\alpha_n^2d^2(x_n,u)\\&\;\;\;\;+\alpha_n [d^{2}(f(u),u)-d^{2}(f(u),x_{n+1})] \end{align}
Then, for all $n\in \mathbb{N},$
\begin{align} [1-\alpha_{n}(k+1)]d^{2}(x_{n+1},u) &\leq
\left[\frac{1+\alpha_{n}(1-2k)}{1-\alpha_{n}(k+1)}\right]  d^{2}(x_{n},u)+\left[\frac{\alpha_n^2}{1-\alpha_{n}(k+1)}\right] 
   d^2(x_n,u)\\&\;\;\;\;+\left[\frac{\alpha_n}{1-\alpha_{n}(k+1)}\right][d^{2}(f(u),u)-d^{2}(f(u),x_{n+1})]\\&\leq
\left[1-\frac{\alpha_{n}(1-2k)}{1-\alpha_{n}(k+1)}\right]  d^{2}(x_{n},u)\\&\;\;\;\;+\left[\frac{\alpha_{n}(1-2k)}{1-\alpha_{n}(k+1)}\right]\left[\frac{\alpha_{n}L}{1-2k}+\frac{d^{2}(f(u),u)-d^{2}(f(u),x_{n+1})}{1-2k}    \right]\end{align}
My problems is "Can we divide by $1-\alpha_{n}(k+1)?$". By simple calculations,$-\frac{1}{2}<1-\alpha_{n}(k+1)<1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so it can be zero. However, let me state the conditions on $\alpha_n$ and $k;$

1. $\alpha_n\in (0,1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N};$
2. $\alpha_n\to 0,$ as $n\to\infty;$
3. $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\alpha_n=\infty;$
4. $k\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right).$

These can be found in [(Eskandani and Raeisi, page 15)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11075-018-0521-3). If it only happens for a large $n$, then $\{\gamma_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\not\subset (0,1)$ towards the end of the page. Can I conclude that this paper is false or I'm I wrong?

Comment: I think they are only using it for sufficiently large $n$, so $1-\alpha_n(k+1)$ is eventually positive and OK to divide by it, no?

Comment: @user10354138: That page (pg. 15) says it happens for all natural numbers. How do we reconcile that?

Comment: Look at what conclusions they draw from it.  It only needs $\sum\gamma_n=\infty$ and similar for 2.18.  Remember leading few terms don't affect convergence.

Comment: @user10354138: If it only happens for a large $n$, then $\{\gamma_n\}\not\subset (0,1)$ towards the end of the page.

Comment: @user10354138: $\sum \gamma<\infty?$

Comment: Huh?  For all large enough $n$, $\gamma_n\in(0,1)$ because it is basically a constant positive multiple of $\alpha_n$.

Comment: @user10354138: I don't think I agree to that.

Comment: @user10354138: I know that $\gamma_n\in(0,1)$ for large $n$ but the convergence theorem I'm using needs it to happen for all natural numbers.

Comment: No, we don't care about the first few terms in any sort of convergence theorem.  It is one of the first lessons of undergraduate analysis.

Comment: @user10354138: I appreciate this discussion with you. However, I do know that finite terms do not matter if you check Lemma 2.18 of the same paper, then you'll know that the hypothesis placed on it is for all natural numbers, not for infinitely many terms.

Comment: You can always shift the index(suffix) and discard the first however many terms as a result.  Nothing is going to change in 2.18 if you do that.

Comment: @user10354138: Thanks a lot, I do appreciate. So, you mean that I can construct another sequence from it or pick a subsequence.

Comment: Yes, here we construct a subsequence which converges iff the original sequence converge.

Comment: @user10354138: Oh, thank you very much! I am so grateful!

Comment: @user10354138: I really appreciate your kind gesture. Here is one final question, though! If I pick a subsequence of the convergence, that will imply that $\{x_{n_k}\}\subset \{x_n\}$ converges strongly to a fixed point but does it guarantee the convergence of the whole sequence $\{x_n\}$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\alpha_n \to 0$$

Hence for large $n$, we have $\alpha_n< \frac1{k+1}$ which is equivalent to

$$1-\alpha_n (k+1)>0$$

Comment: Do you know my concern? That page (pg. 15) says it happens for all natural numbers. How do we reconcile that?

Comment: If it only happens for a large $n$, then $\{\gamma_n\}\not\subset (0,1)$ towards the end of the page.

Comment: Do you think it was because $\alpha_n\to 0?$. If it is so, then $\gamma_n\in (0,1)$ for large $n$, not all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: unfortunately, the linked paper is hidden behind a paywall... but I think you sorted it out in the comments?